# What is the effect of deleting an entity's ancestor on its path?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I have entities `a`, `b` and `c` such that `a` is the parent of `b` and `b` is the parent of `c`, will deleting `b` have any effect on the path of `c`?

Answer (score 5):

No. It's quite possible for an entity to have a parent that no longer exists - the entity, and the identity of its entity group, will remain unchanged.